# Use Twilio For Sip calls in and out through ONSIP.com

Tags: sip

I am not overly technically savy so I am asking the community if this can be done.

I am using ONSIP.com as a hosted PBX solution. ( Its easy and I like their interface.

What I would like to do is use their "bridge function" to have Twilio be the source for my SIP numbers.

I think this can be done because ONSIP describes how I can get an international number from DIDWW>com and have it "pointed" into to my system.   So I thought, why not have Twilio supply me with numbers, local and international.

The real question I have though is can I make calls out on that SIP number, going through ONSIP.com to start the call but have Twilio actually make the call , (if that makes sense)

ONSIP.com charges 2.9/minute in or out bound and it appears as though Twilio is on 1/minute. so it would seem to make sense to do this if it can be done?

Here is their info on an inbound bridge
http://www.junctionnetworks.com/knowledgebase/onsip/admin-portal/apps/inbound-bridge

Thanks for any advice or input you might have on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to find out is if OnSIP and Twilio both support SIP transfers.

To have a call you've started on OnSIP's server "moved" to Twilio it will require the use of SIP REFER requests, which are how call transfers are done in the SIP World. Without a transfer it means your call would end up going through both OnSIP's and Twilio's server and mean you end up incurring both sets of charges.

I suspect you'll find one or both of them don't support transfers since such functionality can be tricky for a SIP provider to implement and it's also it's not going to be in the originating provider's interests, in this case OnSIP, to provide you with a way of avoiding their call charges.

Perhaps an easier way for you would be to get an IP Phone or ATA that has two or more SIP lines and connect the first line to OnSIP for incoming calls and the second line to Twilio for outgoing calls.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this now, Twilio does not support Sip Refer at the time of this post